# Why doesn't LaTeX typeset this reference normally?

Tags: bibtex

***I use the `bibtex` to add my reference.`Reference.bib` as below:***

```
@Book{MathematicaIntroduction,
 author = {袭宗燕著},
 title = {数学软件Mathematica系统的应用及其程序设计[{M}]},
 publisher = {北京大学出版社},
 year = {1996},
}
@Article{InverseMethod,
 author = {刘湘晨，蔡晓君，蒋力培，方徐应},
 title = {机器人运动学分析与求解方法的探讨[{J}]},
 journal = {机床与液压},
 year = {2009},
}
@Book{RobotIntroduction,
 author = {(美)Saeed B. Niku著},
 title = {机器人学导论：分析、控制及应用[{M}]},
 publisher = {电子工业出版社},
 year = {2004},
}

@Manual{PrigrammingMethod,
title = {{B}uilding large software systems in {M}athematica},
author = {Wolfram Research},
organization = {Wolfram Research},
year = {2010},
}
@Article{SCARASimulationPID,
author = {Serhan Yamacli，Huseyin Canbolat},
title = {Simulation of a {SCARA} robot with {PD} and learning controllers[{J}]},
journal = {Simulation {M}odelling {P}ractice and {T}heory},
year = {2008},
}
@Article{DynamicEquation,
author = {陆金伟，李跃民},
title = {{SCARA}机器人的完整动力学显方程的推导[{J}]},
journal = {振动、测试与诊断},
year = {1995},
}

@MastersThesis{ChengDing,
author = {程汀},
title = {{SCARA}机器人的设计及运动、动力学的研究[{D}]},
school = {合肥工业大学},
type = {硕士论文},
year = {2008},
}

@MastersThesis{YuHuaDong,
author = {于华东},
title = {机器人动力学方程的符号法推导及快速计算[{D}]},
school = {北京工业大学},
year = {2002},
type = {硕士论文},
}

@Article{SCARAModel,
author = {Shutao Tang},
title = {A {M}odel of the {SCARA} {R}obot},
journal= {Wolfram Demonstrations Project},
year = {2014},
}
```

some parts of my paper example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,cs4size,UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\section{绪论}
\subsection{数学软件Wolfram Mathematica}

本文的主要是关于SCARA机器人的运动学和动力学研究，涉及到符号计算、数值计算和图形的可视化，这恰好是Mathematica所擅长的领域，因此首先对Mathematica做一个简单的介绍\cite{MathematicaIntroduction}。

在理论研究方面，文献\cite{ChengDing}对SCARA机器人的运动学和动力学进行了符号推导，并利用MATLAB分别进行了仿真，文献\cite{DynamicEquation}对SCARA机器人的动力学方程进行了显式推导，文献\cite{YuHuaDong}受当时计算机硬件水平的限制，采用Mathematica对5自由度的类Rm501机器人进行了动力学的符号推导。Serhan Yamacli和Huseyin Canbolat基于控制器的PD和learning的条件下仿真一种SCARA型机器人操作手\cite{SCARASimulationPID}，利用那些控制器来研究机器人的轨迹跟随性能，并分析了几种控制算法的控制性能。

文献\cite{RobotIntroduction}对D-H坐标系法的原理和使用方法给出了详细的说明，Denavit-Hartenberg(D-H)模型表示了对机器人连杆和关节进行建模的一种非常简单的方法，可用于任何机器人构型，而不管机器人的结构顺序和复杂程度如何。另外，它也可以用于表示全旋转的链式机器人、SCARA机器人或任何可能的关节和连杆组合

对于逆运动学的求解，本文将采用左乘逆矩阵(反变换法)\cite{InverseMethod}，它能够使得要求解的关节变量单独解耦出来

动力学Mathematica程序，将会以文献\cite{RobotIntroduction}P220页的二自由度连杆的动力学实例来进行测试

编写动力学程序的基础，编写程序采用模块化的思想\cite{PrigrammingMethod}，把整个程序划分成不可再分的子程序，这样做的目的是便于调试运行，提高效率。

Mathematica程序\cite{SCARAModel}建立SCARA工业机器人的动态模型，该模型能通过调整4个关节变量的参数来显示末端执行件的位置和姿态。

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}        
\bibliography{Reference}

\end{document}
```

***aftering two compiling,it show as below :***

[image]

***So my question is why and how to revise it?Can someone help me?Thanks sincerely.***

Comment: You are missing a closing brace `}` in entry `YuHuaDong` and `SCARAModel`.

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: @Werner,Ok,I have edited it,Thanks!+1)

Comment: But did that fix your original problem? Yes? No?

Comment: @Werner,No,one item cannot appear normally that it show `于华东. 机器人动力学方程的符号法推导及快速计算[D], school = 北京工业大学, year =
2002,. Master’s thesis.`I wonder why ?

Comment: @mma I copied the current version you have in the question and compiled. The PDF shows nothing wrong.

Comment: @mma: Once you've changed the `.bib` file, you need to rerun it through `bibtex`, otherwise you'll still be stuck with the old set of `}`-less (and problematic) version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by a typo.